# Multi-Author Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wattpad

I am planning to make a website whose theme similar to Wattpad. I would like to know is there any Wordpress theme which is available like that? or having options like allowing users to write stories in my site as well get views and upvotes fo their posts.

I really need it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Themes are not supposed to include special functionality. They supposed to just be the look / style.

You'd need a plugin to show the views & upvotes.  There are many of those.

An example It looks like https://fiftywordstories.com/ is running twenty-thirteen theme with a plugin - view source to see the plugin.